# Pipe null terminated file paths twice to same output, but second time sorted by basename

Tags: find, perl, sort

So, let's say I have a script that uses `find` to print paths with null-terminated filenames.

I also want to print another version of the output where each path is sorted by its basename. I want to achieve this without running `find` again and by piping both outputs to the same command as if they were a single output.

I assume this can be done using Perl, but I'm not very familiar with it.

Here are some important points to consider:

1. The initial output should be passed through unchanged and in real-time. In other words, during the first run, the command should simply output the lines as they are to the second command while capturing them for sorting once the input (e.g., `find`) completes.
2. After `find` (or any other program that outputs zero-terminated paths) completes, the script should sort each received path by its basename. The sorting should ignore everything before the last `/` character, unless the path ends with a trailing slash. In the case of a trailing slash, the sorting should be based on the field before it to ensure that directories with trailing slashes are not grouped together. Once the sorting is complete, the sorted output should be printed after the original output.

How can this be achieved easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With perl, that could look like:

```
find . ... -print0 |
  perl -MFile::Basename -0 -lne '
    print; push @files, $_;
    END {
      print $_->[0] for sort {$a->[1] cmp $b->[1]} map {[$_, basename$_]} @files
    }' | ...
```

With:

- `-MFile::Basename` `use`s the `File::Basename` `M`odule for its `basename()` function
- `-0`: sets the input record separator to the NUL byte
- `-n`: `sed -n` mode where the `-e`xpression is run for each input record.
- `-l`: sets the output record separator to the same thing as the input record separator (NUL here) and strip the input record separator from the end of the record so `$_` contains the contents of the record in the `-e`xpression.
- for each record, we `print` it  (followed by the output record separator), then `push` it onto a `@files` list.
- in the `END`, we loop over a `sort`ed list of a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) of the list.

Comment: Very nice. A possible improvement might be to add `BEGIN { $| = 1; }` to make sure that the leading `print` outputs immediately. This would satisfy point 1.